# ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank in assign_add()

Tags: tensorflow2.0, valueerror

I am reading [tf.Variable in Tensorflow r2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) in TF2:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a variable.
w = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], tf.float32, shape=[2, 2])

# Use the variable in the graph like any Tensor.
y = tf.matmul(w,tf.constant([7, 8, 9, 10], tf.float32, shape=[2, 2]))
v= tf.Variable(w)
# The overloaded operators are available too.
z = tf.sigmoid(w + y)
tf.shape(z)
# Assign a new value to the variable with `assign()` or a related method.
v.assign(w + 1)
v.assign_add(tf.constant([1.0, 21]))
```

> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1 for
>   'AssignAddVariableOp_4' (op: 'AssignAddVariableOp') with input shapes:
>   [], [2](https://youtu.be/Up9CvRLIIIw?t=113).

And also how come the following returns false?

```
tf.shape(v) == tf.shape(tf.constant([1.0, 21],tf.float32))
```

My other question is that when we are in TF 2, we should not use tf.Session() anymore, correct? It seems [we should never run session.run()](https://youtu.be/Up9CvRLIIIw?t=113), but the API document keys doing it with tf.compat.v1, etc. So why they are using it in TF2 docs?

Any help would be appreciated.

CS

Comment: Did you try debugging by printing output line by line.That would help you

Answer (score 0):

As it clearly says in the error, it is expecting shape [2,2] for `assign_add` on v which is having the shape [2,2]. 
If you try to give any shape other than the initial shape of the Tensor which you are trying to do `assign_add` the error will be given.

Below is the modified code with the expected shape for the operation.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a variable.
w = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], tf.float32, shape=[2, 2])

# Use the variable in the graph like any Tensor.
y = tf.matmul(w,tf.constant([7, 8, 9, 10], tf.float32, shape=[2, 2]))
v= tf.Variable(w)
# The overloaded operators are available too.
z = tf.sigmoid(w + y)
tf.shape(z)
# Assign a new value to the variable with `assign()` or a related method.
v.assign(w + 1)
print(v)
v.assign_add(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], tf.float32, shape=[2, 2]))
```

Output for v:

```
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[3., 5.],
       [7., 9.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Now the following Tensor comparison is returning `True`.

```
tf.shape(v) == tf.shape(tf.constant([1.0, 21],tf.float32))
```

> `<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([ True,  True])>`

Coming to your `tf.Session()` question, in TensorFlow 2.0 eager execution is enabled by default, still, if you need to disable eager execution and can use `tf.Session` like below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

print(sess.run(hello))
```